# AWS AutoScaling Simple Scaling policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I have one scale in **simple policy** in my autoscaling group which is based on CPU Utilization.
The policy looks like:

```
Execute :
When CPUUtilization < 50 for 5 consecutive periods of 60 seconds 
Action : 
Remove 10 percent of group
Cooldown time:
600 seconds before allowing another scaling activity
```

Now I would like to add a more aggressive simple policy, saying if `CPUUtilization` is less than 35 for 5 minutes, remove `20%` of the group.

The goal is

> When 35 < CPU Utilization < 50 for 5 minutes, remove 10% of the group
>
> When CPU Utilization < 35 for 5 minutes, remove 20% of the group

The problem is I cannot use **scaling policy with steps** since the cooldown time is not supported which could make my asg scaling in until the min instances.

And if I have both simple policies, they are obviously conflict. I don't really know which policy will be triggered first if it reachs `CPUUtilization < 35`.

Does anyone have a workaround of this one?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share what goal are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @KunalPradhan goal is added in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would certainly need to use **Scaling Policy with Steps** to be able to specify multiple rules for the scaling policy. While it doesn't allow the specification of a Cooldown period, it should work fine. I recommend you try it and monitor/test the system.

By the way, you have a **very aggressive** policy. It is not typically a good idea to scale-in based upon only 5 minutes of data. Amazon EC2 is charged in hourly increments, so you might be *thrashing* (adding and removing instances very quickly), which is not economical. It is typically recommended to scale-out quickly (to respond to user demand) but scale-in slowly (since there's really no rush).

Comment: Unfortunately the policy with steps doesn't work for scaling in because of the cooldown time. I made a test and the scale in policy was triggered one after another until it reached the min instances set in the asg.